# jQuery - Runs Animation Only Once In a Session

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am using the follwing function to start an animation when the page first load. And it works fine.

```
function checkAnimation_ss() {
    var $elem = $('.ss');
    // If the animation has already been started
    if ($elem.hasClass('icon_start')) return; //or same session??
    if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
        // Start the animation
        $elem.addClass('icon_start');
    }
}
```

My Problem is that when i navigate to another page and then hit the "Back" butto of the browser, the animation starts again.

Is there a way to let the animation runs only once in a session?
I knew that I need to use jquery.cookie.js in a way, I just can't figure it out?

Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Yeah you could use a var as a flag and store it in a cookie or use localstorage, then see if it exists on .ready. You may also want have a look at window.history

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use cookie with jquery.cookie.js, in that case you would want to do something similar to:

```
 function checkAnimation_ss() {
var cookieValue = $.cookie("animation");
if(cookieValue == 1)
{}
else
{
    var $elem = $('.ss');
    // If the animation has already been started
    if ($elem.hasClass('icon_start')) return; //or same session??
    if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
        // Start the animation
        $elem.addClass('icon_start');
        $.cookie("animation", 1);
    }
}}
```

Of course you can also solve it with php if your site uses it. In such case you could do something like:

```
<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['animation'] = 1; ?>
```

And then:

```
function checkAnimation_ss() {
<?php 
    if($_SESSION['animation'] == 1)
    {}
    else
    {
?>
    var $elem = $('.ss');
    // If the animation has already been started
    if ($elem.hasClass('icon_start')) return; //or same session??
    if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
        // Start the animation
        $elem.addClass('icon_start');
        $.cookie("animation", 1);
    }
<?php 
}
?>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Final Code ...

```
function checkAnimation_ss() {

    var cookieValue = $.cookie("animation");
    var $elem = $('.ss');
    if(cookieValue == 1){
        $elem.addClass('icon_visible');
    }else{
      // If the animation has already been started
      if ($elem.hasClass('icon_start')) return;
      if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
          // Start the animation
          $elem.addClass('icon_start');
          $.cookie("animation", 1);
      }
    }

}
```